# Jquery to check if form fields are required before modal pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi have a form which has two submit buttons:

(Button 2)The user clicks the submit button and a modal pop up appears and in the modal is some T&Cs they have to accept, (Button 1) once they click accept the second submit button does the form submission.

There are required form fields that don't show (required) once the first button is pressed just the modal pop up comes, How can I achieve this? My Jquery code is:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#login-form button").click(function (ev) {
                ev.preventDefault()
                if ($(this).attr("value") == "button1") {
                    // alert("First Button is pressed")
                    $("#login-form").submit();
                }
                if ($(this).attr("value") == "button2") {
                    $(".modal").addClass("active");
                }
            });
        });
```

The form field is:

```
<label class="form-label" for="firstname">First name:</label>
<input class="form-input" required type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="firstname>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little code i wrote, i try to make it as dynamic as possible.
Instead of click you should have it `onchange` but its really upp to you.

make sure too look at `validationType`

```js
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
if ($(this).hasClass("disable"))
return false;

if ($(this).hasClass("validate")){
var errors = [];
// all required input that need validation
var input = $(this).parent().find("input[type='text'][required='required']");
input.each(function(){
var vType= $(this).attr("validationType");
var value =$(this).val(); 
var fName =$(this).attr("placeholder"); 
switch(vType){
case "notEmpty":
if (!value || value== "")
  errors.push(fName +" cant be empty");
break;
}
});
if (errors.length>0){
  $(this).parent().find(".submit").addClass("disable");
   alert(errors)
   }
   else {
     $(this).parent().find(".submit").removeClass("disable");
   }

}else return true; // submit the form

});
```

```css
input[required="required"]{
border:1px solid red;
}

.disable{
 color:#CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="text" validationType="notEmpty" required="required" value="" placeholder="firstName" />
<input type="button" class="validate" value="button 1" />

<input type="button" class="submit disable" value="button 2" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is how steps works on my own way .. The idea here is the first form is a main one and the second is a just for users not for programming .. This means the first form will have all the required fields and I will hide the fields and control it with javascript from the fake form

- I create two forms one is a main and the second is a fake one
- I add a hidden checkbox in a main form
- I make separated submit events for each form
- I made a change event for the fake checkbox to control the main checkbox in the main form

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Main Form Submit
  $("#mainForm").on("submit" , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#mainCheck").is(":checked")){
      alert("First Form is Submitted correctly");
    }else{
      //alert('Show Modal With Form');
      $("#fakeForm").show();
    }
  });
  // Fake form in Modal submit
  $("#fakeForm").on("submit" , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#fakeCheck").is(":checked")){
      $("#mainForm").submit();
    }else{
      alert("Please Accept our policies first");
    }
  });
  // fake checkbox to change main checkbox
  $("#fakeCheck").on("change" , function(){
    $("#mainCheck").prop("checked" , this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
#mainForm, #fakeForm{
  background : #eee;
  border : 5px solid #555;
  margin : 20px;
  padding : 20px;
}
#mainCheckLabel,#fakeForm{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- first Form -->
<form id="mainForm">
  <label class="form-label" for="firstname">First name:</label>
  <input class="form-input" required type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="firstname" />
  <br/>
  <label id="mainCheckLabel"><input type="checkbox" id="mainCheck"/>Accept to our policies</label>
  <button type="submit">Submit First Form</button>
</form>
<!-- End First Form -->

<!-- Second Form in Modal -->
<form id="fakeForm">
  <label id="fakeCheckLabel"><input type="checkbox" id="fakeCheck"/>Accept to our policies</label>
  <button type="submit">Submit Second Form</button>
</form>
<!-- End Second Form in Modal -->
```

**Note** hide the `#mainCheckLabel` in the main form

**Example of how to use `[required]` selector**

```js
$('input[required]').css('border' , '1px solid red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" required placeholder="First Name"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed but all I want is to show the fields are required.

Comment: @Sole I can't get the point .. I gave you full example of how to do two forms submit .. you need to work around this to got it to work for yours .. for the required fields you still can use `[required]` selector  to select the required fields

Comment: @Sole I updated my answer with how to use `[required]` selector

Answer (score 0):

Following solution works for me:

```js
$("#uploadBtn").click(function() {
  var form_data = new FormData($("#data-uploader-form")[0])
  if ($("#data-uploader-form")[0].checkValidity()) {
    alert("valid form")
  } else {
    alert("incorrect form")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='data-uploader-form' onsubmit='return false;'>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Input field</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="testInputField" placeholder="some text" required="required">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-left" id="uploadBtn">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Vishal, why have you got `onsubmit=""return false`?

Comment: Good question. If you see button type for submit button is 'submit', which means if you enter it, it actually submits the form. Instead I wanted to invoke my custom click() event when I click on it $("#uploadBtn").click(function() {...}